# How do i get this Hex string converted to Date in java

Tags: java, date, hex, data-conversion, snmp-trap

I am trying to convert hex string "`07e4070e04032b`" to date and below is my code:

```
String hexmillis1 = "07e4070e04032b";
long convertedMillis1 = Long.decode("0x" + hexmillis1);
Instant instant1 = Instant.ofEpochMilli(convertedMillis1);
LocalDateTime localDateTime1 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant1, ZoneId.systemDefault());

System.out.println(localDateTime1.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
```

Output:  `+72352-01-29T13:17:02.571`

Expected output is a date and time earlier today, so 2020-07-14 or perhaps 2020-07-13.

I have tried few other ways also but it does not seem to give correct date.

The hex string is coming from a SNMP trap. Not sure of how it was exactly encoded.

Comment: Do you what the other way ? How the hex value has been obtained ?

Comment: What is the meaning of the hex string? I.e. how is the time encoded in it?

Comment: @azro, @@henry - it is comming from a snmp trap. Not sure of how it is exactly converted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i found my solution at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700037/snmp-eventtime-in-human-readable-format-in-java

Comment: For your next question about code that gives a surprising result: Please state what result you had expected. Then we can much better help you how to obtain that result.

Comment: I took this occasion for writing [a new answer for you here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62902927/5772882).

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://currentmillis.com/?2221043788022571) the conversion is right.

What is wrong there is the hex value:

**07e4070e04032b** == **2221043788022571**

Comment: Wrong. SNMP trap date-time strings don’t work this way. See the linked original question for the correct answers. Or [this](https://www.webnms.com/snmp/help/snmpapi/snmpv3/using_mibs_in_applns/tcs_dateandtime.html).

Comment: @OleV.V. as far I answered, I didn't know about data comes from SNMP trap, I've just help guy debugging his problem confirming the conversion performed was right and the problem was in the hex source.